# No volver a actualizar filas anteriormene actualizadas con UPDATE de SQLITE

Tags: python, sqlite

Quisiera saber como poner una condición en `UPDATE` para que solo pueda actualizar campos vacíos y no las que ya contengan datos

```
"UPDATE bienes SET Inv = ? WHERE CodInt = {id}"
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a [es.so], te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. ¿Qué has intentado hacer hasta el momento? Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que los usuarios publiquen sus preguntas junto con lo que han intentado, de esa forma se demuestra que has hecho un esfuerzo por resolver tu pregunta/problema, de lo contrario probablemente la pregunta termine cerrada y/o votada negativamente. Lectura recomendada: [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Jackson-Quintero no te dirijas al OP a través de un resumen de edición. Para eso están los comentarios :)

Comment: Añade `AND LENGTH(campo)=0` al `UPDATE` que has propuesto y únicamente te actualizará los campos vacíos

Comment: @DavidJP depende de a que se refiera el OP con "vacios". Una "celda" con valor Null tambien se puede considerar vacía. Y en ese caso la funcion length no sirve a ese proposito.

Comment: @DanteS. Entonces haz: `AND (LENGTH(campo)=0 OR campo IS NULL)` y también te funcionará para los nulos

Comment: A lo que me refiero, es que el termino "vacío" es ambiguo y nos vendría bien que el OP aclare a que se refiere con eso.